# Draw Marker in Image

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I'm drawing a picture using Matplotlib:

```
plt.imshow(bild)
plt.show()
```

How do I add a Marker to this (eg. red dot / arrow) using the coordinates of the image?

Answer (score 14):

You can also use [`plt.scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) to add a red dot to mark the point. Building on the previous answer's example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = np.random.randn(100, 100)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img)
plt.annotate('25, 50', xy=(25, 50), xycoords='data',
             xytext=(0.5, 0.5), textcoords='figure fraction',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
plt.scatter(25, 50, s=500, c='red', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use the module [matplotlib.patches](https://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html) as shown below. Notice that in order to place a patch at the **x**<sup>*th*</sup> row and **y**<sup>*th*</sup> column of the image you need to reverse the order of the coordinates, i.e. `y, x` when instantiating the corresponding patch.

```
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arrow, Circle

maze = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQCy9.png')

ax, ay = 300, 25
dx, dy = 0, 75
cx, cy = 300, 750

patches = [Arrow(ay, ax, dy, dx, width=100., color='green'),
           Circle((cy, cx), radius=25, color='red')]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.imshow(maze)
for p in patches:
    ax.add_patch(p)
plt.show(fig)
```

[image: Annotated image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function [`plt.annotate`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) for this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = np.random.randn(100, 100)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.annotate('25, 50', xy=(25, 40), xycoords='data',
             xytext=(0.5, 0.5), textcoords='figure fraction',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
plt.show()
```