# Mark particular pixel location on image

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I have an image of size `256*256`. I am displaying this image by the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
```

I have another array of size 20*2, which contains 20-pixel locations on the image which I want to mark using marker '+'.

Is there any easier way to achieve this? Using matplotlib or cv2?

Comment: Using cv2... by numpy's narray

Answer (score 3):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = plt.imread("t.png") # your image
x = np.random.rand(1, 20)*img.shape[1]
y = np.random.rand(1, 20)*img.shape[0]
size = 50 # size of marker

plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray") # plot image
plt.scatter(x, y, size, c="r", marker="+") # plot markers
plt.show()
```

It's plot like that:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use `plot` function to plot your coordinates with `+` option and any colour you want.

[image: result]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

# img = cv2.imread('input_image.jpg')
img = np.ones((256,256))

arr = np.array([[20,20],[30,30], [40,40], [50,50], [20,20],[30,30], [40,40], [50,50],
 [20,20],[30,30], [20,20],[30,30], [60,60], [155,155], [120,120],[130,130], [140,140], [150,150],
  [220,220],[230,230] ])

print(arr.shape)

for x,y in arr:
    plt.plot(x, y, 'r+', linewidth=2, markersize=12)

plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = np.random.randn(100, 100)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img)
plt.annotate('25, 50', xy=(25, 50), xycoords='data',
             xytext=(0.5, 0.5), textcoords='figure fraction',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
plt.scatter(25, 50, s=500, c='white', marker='+') # Here you can change the coordinates and the color and marker
plt.show()
```

I found this on this thread, have a look if you want to see some more answers
[Draw Marker in Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551536/draw-marker-in-image#38708648)